# jQuery : selecting an element whose content is exactly such and such

Tags: jquery

I want to select all A elements whose content is exactly "^" (these are return to top links). How to do that ?

Comment: It would be a hell of a lot easier if you tagged them with a particular class or name.

Comment: Sorry I meant A elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they are anchor tags, you could use:

```
$("a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "^";
}).wrapInner("<span />");
```

**Updated for comment**

Comment: @undefined Possibly, but if it is ' ^' it isn't *"exactly "^""*

Comment: Kavin B : sorry I haven't seen your answer. Please could you tell how I can use your code to actually wrap this "^" with SPAN tags ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the contains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/...

```
$("a:contains('^')");
```

Whilst it wont match only the exact string, but strings containing that text, it may be good enough. If not, you can use the filter as other answers suggest. For clarity...

**EDIT** Sorry, updated using the `text` method would also match any parent wrapping elements as the child elements would be stripped, if you want only the direct element that contains the text node with the content "^" instead use the `html` method...

```
$("a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).html() === "^";
});
```

I have created an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7fXUH/,

**EDIT** My last point above is less relevant now the tag has been specified, you are unlikely to nest anchors within anchors but just in any case it might be useful to note.

Comment: Will also pick up any elements that have `^` anywhere in regular text. Like: `<div>Hello ^.^</div>`

Comment: This also selects the parents of the element that have `^` text content and is not an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":contains('^')")
```

[Doc jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Same as I told Stuart Wakefield: it will pick up `^` anywhere in the text such as: `<div>Look before you leap! ^O^</div>`

Comment: You asked exactly 'elements whose content is exactly "^"'

Comment: I didn't ask, but the questions states "exactly" as you point out. Yours will hit _more_ than exactly those.